# apache ext_filter module not work

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I need to filter some words in apache output pages.

this is my filter code:

```
ExtFilterDefine fixtext mode=output cmd="/bin/sed s/works/sorta/ig"

<Location />
    SetOutputFilter fixtext
</Location>
```

but, when I use this codes my output is like this:

> ‹í½{“Ü6’/ú÷Î§¨é™qµŽ\­â«²ZK»ë¸cÙ3¶wÃ«[Á"QUTó%‚¬êÖžùî7‘ $_U’Ø»qOïŽÕMü H$&“ÉäÅï_ÿðíÏ¿þøfrÈ£pòã/ùëwßN®fÏžý»õí³g¯~=ùßÿúó÷7óÉÏ™ó ’Ø Ÿ={óöjruÈóôù³g§ÓéædÝ$ÙþÙÏv/h"sùë,×rÞø¹õòwQºH­~e®/Å?ó ÙË7Gç“ŸÝ œü[ÀN,{ñL&(`Äw“Œ…·W<?0–*Mò‡”Ý^åì>æq~59dlw{usóAÏÜãÆK¢(‰o õÏùíÜœ³õj±Zx¦³Ü:[flmËZ2wn[;Ï\=ûÒß(Xöpãy%§!Ë™({,Â³"˜7Ë¯àyU”iîeAšë´Þ»GW~½šðÌCŠïyUÏ(ˆoÞó«—/žIÌËÏ µÏØÃ6¹ÿb:]¬K]ï®A¸›ò´AyªÅÏÑÍ&î{÷þ‡í{øëvaøM‘ºgø×ídç†œµ!E–ÝN¦Ž?¹ÍO“ØgÙô›v¡Ÿ•ÅµÓxÊ˜*³æóy»

can anybody help me to solve this problem??

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault, please take a look at [How to ask a good question](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `intype` or else it will mess with everything in an undefined way.

```
ExtFilterDefine fixtext mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/bin/sed s/a/b/g"

<Location />
    SetOutputFilter fixtext
</Location>
```